# defautl image in the field "ImageField" - Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I try to put an image in an ImageField by default. But I can't solve the problem.

My first attempt at solution was the following:

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders

result = finders.find('img/image.png')
models.ImageField(upload_to = user_model_custom_upload, default = result)
```

My second attempt at solution was the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
import os

DEFAULT_AVATAR_PATH = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images/no-avatar.png')

models.ImageField(upload_to = user_model_custom_upload, default = DEFAULT_AVATAR_PATH)
```

neither solution worked

But something curious happens with the second method, is that at the time that Django searches for the image, the image path for Django is as follows:

```
Not Found: /media/home/lcteen/Documents/Programming/Frameworks/Django/ibme_project/media/images/no-avatar.png
```

I don't know what is currently happening, it's like the structure of my directories is in the media folder or something ... but my media folder doesn't change at all.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Provide `'images/no-avatar.png'` to default argument

```
models.ImageField(upload_to = user_model_custom_upload, default = 'images/no-avatar.png')
```

and put below in your project `url conf.`

```
if settings.DEBUG: 
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and make sure that in your `settings.py` file

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I have a question: At the time of doing the "collectstatic" will bring problems when displaying the image?

Comment: You are welcome.. 
No it will not create problem. your images will be in media folder and `collectstatic` will copy all static files like ` css, js etc...` in your `STATIC_ROOT` while deploying your application. For displaying images it will not create problem. If you find anything like that you can share here.